# why calling a virtual function in c++ means message dispatch

Tags: c++

What is the rationale/explanation of saying that calling a virtual function is "message dispatching" in c++? Particularly what message is being dispatched?

Comment: It's "dynamic dispatch", not "message dispatch".

Comment: The "message" thing comes from OO terminology of Smalltalk, where calling a method is referred as "passing a message to the object".

Comment: Should be message dispatch. lvella did provides some explanation. I just want more elaboration. "passing a message to the object" is like "telling the object what to do"?

Answer (score 0):

It is called "[Dynamic Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch)".

Comment: So, are you saying the premise of the question is invalid, and that it's *never* called message dispatching? If so, please say so. Otherwise, I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

In programming languages, message passing is a model of communication often associated with Object Oriented programming, in which structures representing packets/messages (information to be exchanged) are sent from one point to another (may be the same program or different programs) and are copied in their entirety.

This is opposed to function calling, where in many cases a simple address is passed over for performance reasons.

Virtual function calls are, as the name implies, function calls, so they have nothing to share with message passing (except that at low-level you still need functions to pass messages around). Yet, for simplicity's sake, many textbooks present function calling in C++/Java/... as "passing a message to an object".

Virtual functions "dispatch" a certain function call through the class hierarchy in the following sense: if one creates an object of a derived class, but makes a call to a virtual function using a base class pointer, then the real object type (derived) is resolved at run-time and the overridden function is called (assuming it is available). This mechanism of choosing the right target for a function call at run-time (instead of compile time) is called Dynamic binding or Dynamic dispatch.

```
#include <stdio.h>
class Base{
public:
  virtual void echo(){ printf( "Base echo()\n"; ) }
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
  void echo(){ printf( "Derived echo()\n"; ) }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
  Derived d_obj;
  Base * b_ptr = &d_obj;
  b_ptr->echo(); 
  // This prints "Derived echo()" even though b_ptr is of type Base pointer
  return 0;
}
```